# can I sort NSMutable array of NSStrings by their substrings using the selector (in place)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` consisting out of `NSString`s. When I need to sort it, I use `[array sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]` which works perfect.

But sometimes I need to sort the array by substrings of `NSString`s. The substring is defined in this case as part of `NSString` following some marker. The thing is complicated further by the fact that marker can be positioned differently in every string.

Obviously I can break `NSString` into 2 objects and do sorting on them but it will require significant changes.

Is there a way to do the sorting using selector similar to what I have described above?

I think if not, then I might sort by creating a sorted copy of an array (instead of using selector to do it in place), then releasing the original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can perform any arbitrarily complex sorting inline with NSMutableArray's [sortWithOptions:usingComparator](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortWithOptions:usingComparator:):

```
[myMutableArray sortWithOptions:NSSortStable usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString* str1, NSString* str2) {

    // Scan for your marker in both strings and split on it...
    // Say you store the results in substr1 and substr2...
    return [substr1 caseInsensitiveCompare:substr2];
}];
```

Comment: Matt, thank you very much. I didn't know about this functionality. Best Regards, Victor